# How to make counter section one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I created a counter section where it goes from 0 to a specific number. However, all three counterts start at the same time.

Is there any possibilities that first counter 1 counts up, as soon as it is finished counter 2 counts up and so on. Respectively every counter counts up one by one.

Here I created a Pen [project](https://codepen.io/zenunbeh/pen/QWpBBRK).

```css
.counts {
  padding: 70px 0 60px;
}

.counts .count-box {
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f1f6fe;
}

.counts .count-box i {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #106eea;
  color: #fff;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.counts .count-box span {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #062b5b;
}

.counts .count-box p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<section id="counts" class="counts">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="100" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Counter 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bx bxl-bitcoin"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="10036" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Counter 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bx bx-server"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="1000" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Counter 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@srexi/purecounterjs/dist/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since you're using a specific library for this and not coding the JavaScript yourself, you should look at it's documentation

Comment: I already looked at is but don't now where to find it. Can you help me here: https://github.com/srexi/purecounterjs

Comment: Please update the snippet I made to a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan You forgot to add bootstrap & jquery, see my edit for a fix

Comment: Since you know the duration you could try to start the next counter after a timeout. But it seems like the counter only starts if it's inside the viewport.

Comment: Having briefly read the documentation for the library you are using, it appears that the API does not expose any events that can notify when a counter has finished. it is also not possible to "connect" counters or set dependencies to other counters. You may need to consider an alternative solution - writing your own JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seem to work

```js
const scr1 = document.createElement("script")
scr1.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@srexi/purecounterjs/dist/purecounter_vanilla.js"
const scr2 = document.createElement("script")
scr2.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@srexi/purecounterjs/dist/purecounter_vanilla.js"

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("counter2").classList.add("purecounter")
  let head = document.querySelector("head")
  head.appendChild(scr1)
}, 2000)
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("counter3").classList.add("purecounter")
  let head = document.querySelector("head")
  head.appendChild(scr2)
}, 5000)
```

```css
.counts {
  padding: 70px 0 60px;
}

.counts .count-box {
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f1f6fe;
}

.counts .count-box i {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #106eea;
  color: #fff;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.counts .count-box span {
  font-size: 36px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #062b5b;
}

.counts .count-box p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<section id="counts" class="counts">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="100" class="purecounter"></span>
          <p>Counter 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-md-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bx bxl-bitcoin"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="10036" id="counter2"></span>
          <p>Counter 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
        <div class="count-box">
          <i class="bx bx-server"></i>
          <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="1000" id="counter3"></span>
          <p>Counter 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@srexi/purecounterjs/dist/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
<!-- End Counts Section -->
```